# How to edit content of Material UI Card

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am displaying few details in Material UI card and have an 'Edit' button. On click of Edit button, i need to update the card content within the same Card layout. Here is the code

```
<Card className={classes.root} variant="outlined">
  <CardContent>
    <Typography
      className={classes.title}
      color="textSecondary"
      gutterBottom
    >
      Word of the Day
    </Typography>
    <Typography>Name: 'RAAM'</Typography>
    <Typography>Blood group: 'AB+'</Typography>
    <Typography>"Patient Ram is having bloodgroup AB+"</Typography>
  </CardContent>
  <CardActions>
    <Button size="small" onClick={click}>
      Edit
    </Button>
  </CardActions>
</Card>
```

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-y54s9?file=/demo.js:721-1283)
How to get the edit functionality working?

Comment: Don't you have to use `state`?

Comment: @GyuHyeonChoi Yup, State is there, once get an idea how to get the update functionality working, can update the state pretty easily, so mocked up local data

Comment: How should be the mechanics of this edit button: should it open a modal? Or turn the typography fields editable?

Comment: @tomrlh Turn the typography fields editable is what i am trying to get.

Answer (score 2):

```
  const [editing, setEditing] = useState(false);

  return (
    <Card className={classes.root} variant="outlined">
      <CardContent>
        { editing ? (
          <textarea>
            editing
          </textarea>
        ) : (
          <div>
            <Typography
              className={classes.title}
              color="textSecondary"
              gutterBottom
            >
              Word of the Day
            </Typography>
            <Typography>Name: 'RAAM'</Typography>
            <Typography>Blood group: 'AB+'</Typography>
            <Typography>"Patient Ram is having bloodgroup AB+"</Typography>
          </div>
        )}
      </CardContent>
      <CardActions>
        <Button size="small" onClick={() => setEditing(true)}>
          Edit
        </Button>
      </CardActions>
    </Card>
  );
```

Not the same layout, however, you can provide editable view of the same layout in this way depending on the `editing` state.

Answer (score 0):

I think is better to use Input fields instead of Typography components. I've put an example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-bj65y).
When you click in edit, the input fields are editable and when it loses focus it is blocked for editing:

```
// all imports here

const useStyles = makeStyles({
[...]
});

export default function OutlinedCard() {
  const [isEditable, setIsEditable] = useState(false);
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const classes = useStyles();

  const handleEdit = () => {
    console.log("I am here");
    setIsEditable(!isEditable);
  };

  return (
    <Card className={classes.root} variant="outlined">
      <CardContent>
        <Typography
          className={classes.title}
          color="textSecondary"
          gutterBottom
        >
          Word of the Day
        </Typography>
        <TextField
          id="standard-basic"
          label="Name:"
          disabled={!isEditable}
          value={name}
          onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
          onBlur={() => setIsEditable(false)}
        />
      </CardContent>
      <CardActions>
        <Button size="small" onClick={handleEdit}>
          Edit
        </Button>
      </CardActions>
    </Card>
  );
}
```